# jQuery selector performance

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some questions on selector performance.

This is my markup (simplified). Child divs are going to have one of two possible classes ('playlist-non-selected' or 'playlist-selected').

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="playlist-non-selected"></div>
    <div class="playlist-selected"></div>
    <div class="playlist-non-selected"></div>
    <div class="playlist-non-selected"></div>
</div>
```

1.
If I want to select all direct children of wrapper div and perform actions on each of them would I use this?

```
wrapper.find('div.playlist-non-selected, div.playlist-selected').each(function(){

});
```

2.
If I want to select specific item would I use this?

```
wrapper.children('div.playlist-non-selected, div.playlist-selected').eq(2);
```

or:

```
wrapper.find('div.playlist-non-selected, div.playlist-selected').eq(2);
```

or:

```
wrapper.children('div').eq(2);
```

These selectors work but I was wondering how efficient are they?

Comment: The question I had when I read this is the frequency of use.  Regarding efficiency, if your going to be performing a lot of operations on the children it can be benificial to cache the wrapper.children() and then filter() to get which ones you want to work on and bypass the dom lookup all together.

Comment: If you want to compare performance of different selectors, use jsperf.com to test them. It's hard to predict the performance without benchmarking.

Answer (score 3):

The jquery selectors are powerful, and the best way I have found to understand them is to simply set code up like you have, and then play in the javascript console of your browser to see what works.

You also need to think about what you are trying to do specifically based on how you are designing your code.

In the first case it looks like you are simply selecting all children of the div.wrapper.  So you would just say `$('div.wrapper').children()`

I would not like to see you ever have a hard coded number like "2" stuck in there.  It may work, but your code will be very brittle.  Instead tag the specific item with a class, and search for that.

As far as effeciency goes.  Its all very fast, and I suggest not worrying about it.  Get the code to work, get it written well, and then worry about speed IF there is a problem

Answer (score 0):

Both find() and children() methods are used to filter the child of the matched elements, except the former is travels any level down, the latter is travels a single level down.

**`find()`** – goes deep down to any number, searching the matched element.

**`children()`** – it just goes one level down of the matched element.

So if `find` and `children` are returning same set of results, then `children` will be doing either equal or less number of comparison.

Comparing the third one with the second one, more the precise selector more efficient it will be as it will limit the number of comparison made.

So out of all three second on is the mose efficient selector.